# clang-format configuration to break before else

Tags: objective-c, clang, clang-format

I created a `.clang-format` for my Objective-C project because some collaborators in my team just don't format their code correctly.

Unfortunately they don't seem to learn / listen the format guidelines.

I'm using `BreakBeforeBraces: Attach` which fits my needs perfectly except one little thing: We'd like to break before else. According to the documentation, the code get's formatted like this:

```
if (condition) {
    //
} else {
    //
}
```

Here is an example of how I need it:

```
- (BOOL)methodWithStatement:(BOOL)statement {
    if (statement) {
        //
    }
    else {
        //
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Is that possible? Maybe not with the options available but I saw something like a reg ex in an example config. Would that be a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "BreakBeforeBraces: Allman".
To get all the configrations u want, u can look into the guide http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html